# A Webhook contact form for Discord in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, discord, contact-form

So I'll start out by saying, that I am a bit new to this.

So I have this website I'm currently making. It's a guild website for World of Warcraft, and we want to be able to have new people being able to apply for membership.

Making the contact form is easy enough through plugins, but this is in theory what I wish to make:

A contact form where when filled in, the application form will push a notification to a webhook set in Discord where when new applicants happen, a message in a channel will be made, notifying the leaders about it.

Do I need to create a plugin myself, or is there any plugin that can offer this functionality?

Comment: I think it will be very hard to find a plugin which can fulfil your requirement. You will have to develop your own functionality for this. Via plugin or theme customisation is your choice.

Comment: It's a kind of a bummer, because i did find a notification plugin that did offer the functionality of webhook notification. But it didn't offer application forms as trigger. :-/

Comment: Well, in that case, you can probably try and customise the notification plugin to enable application forms as trigger. May be by over riding its action/hook which lists the available triggers and their subsequent flow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same needs, after sometime i found a way to do it.

**Its actually very simple with WPForms.**

WPForms has [hooks](https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_process_complete/) so you can easily track forms submitions with the `wpforms_process_complete` hook. This hook allows you to track **ALL** WPForms sumbission. But maybe you'd like to have different forms. If you wish to track only a specific form, you can add the form id to the end of the hook name.

In my case i had many different forms which are being handled in various different ways, so i had to split them. When a **form** is being created in WPForms, **it receives an ID** so does the **fields** of the named form.

In my case after my form was created it had the following id :

[image]

**The hook function.**

As explained on the [Discord Webhook page](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook), Webhooks are a low-effort way to post messages to channels in Discord. They do not require a bot user or authentication to use. The endpoint supports both JSON and form data bodies. In my case i went for JSON.

As explained [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) you just need to use one of the the `content` `file` or `embeds` field. On this example i will just send a message, so i'll be using the `content` field.

Once the above instructions applied, you should end up with something close to the following function :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'discord_form_submission' ) ) :

    /**
     * This will fire at the very end of a (successful) form entry.
     *
     * @link  https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_process_complete/
     *
     * @param array  $fields    Sanitized entry field values/properties.
     * @param array  $entry     Original $_POST global.
     * @param array  $form_data Form data and settings.
     * @param int    $entry_id  Entry ID. Will return 0 if entry storage is disabled or using WPForms Lite.
     */
    function discord_form_submission( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) 
    {
        // You have to replace this url by your discord webhook.
        $endpoint = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/{webhook.id}/{webhook.token}';
        
        // This is the content you can put anything you wish.
        // In my case i needed the Name, Class, and the Level of the players.
        $content  = "**Name :** " . $fields[1]['value'] . PHP_EOL;
        $content .= "**Class :** " . $fields[2]['value'] . PHP_EOL;
        $content .= "**Level :** " . $fields[3]['value'] . PHP_EOL;
        
        // WP has its own tool to send remote POST request, better use it.
        wp_remote_post( $endpoint , [ 
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ],
            'body' => wp_json_encode([ // Same for the JSON encode.
                'content' => $content,
            ]),
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data_format' => 'body'
        ]);
    }
    
endif;
```

This function must be added in the `functions.php` file of your theme.

Last but not least, with the help of the WP [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) Function you need to hook up with the `wpforms_process_complete` hook. In my case since i want to only hook up to the form with the id 1862 i have added the id at the end of the hook which gives us the following code :

```
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete_1862', 'discord_form_submission', 10, 4 );
```

This code must be added in the `functions.php` file of your theme after our newly added function.